Adjusting Memo object height based on the freespace of the report page
I'm stuck with formatting of my report. my report has master-detail-subdetailband each band has it's footer. here is the screenshot of the report, as you can see on the report, i've added extra memo on both detail3band and footer2band.
is there a way to adjust the memo objects height based on the available free space on the report.
